# multiprocessing map keeps running script not function

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

hey im trying to speed up my code by using multiprocessing pool and in theory this:

```py
    def render_frame(i):
        #os.system(f'python main.py video_imgs/out{i}.png {convo}')
        print(f'done {i}')
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pic_list = list(range(1,num_of_pics))
        with Pool(10) as p:
            s = p.map(render_frame,pic_list)
```

should print done then the number i, but when I run the script it just gives me the input prompt I have at the beginning of the script 10 times, which is ->

```py
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    import sys
    import os
    import time
    
    if(len(sys.argv) > 1):
        vidLoc = sys.argv[1]
        convo = sys.argv[2]
    else:
        vidLoc = input('video: ') #! <-- this is being repeated 10 times
        convo = input('convolute cfg file: ')
```

any help? thanks

Comment: The os.system() call is commented in the code you provided. Are you sure you provided the correct code snippet?

Comment: @ThiagoF.Pappacena yes it is the right snippet I was testing and seeing if that was the issue but to no avail

Comment: If you are hitting the else part in main.py, that means that there were no arguments passed to it likely from this line: `#os.system(f'python main.py video_imgs/out{i}.png {convo}')` <- what is `{convo}` in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On systems that use `'spawn'` as the default `multiprocessing` start method (Windows, MacOS), you *must* guard all "main script-like" behaviors under the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard. The `'spawn'` method simulates a `fork` by importing the main module in each child process but with a non-`__main__` name; if you do stuff like calling `input` outside the guard, it will get executed in your child processes. Generally, you should stick to simple imports and function/class/constant definitions outside the guard, never do anything "active" unless you're under the guard (e.g. avoid invoking functions with observable side-effects like `input`).

Guard the `input` code properly (you may just want to omit it as it's odd to allow optional command line arguments that you prompt for otherwise, and annoying to have them reflected in the child processes), and if you must use `input`, find other ways to initialize the variables in the child process (e.g. by means of an `initializer` function with `initargs`, both are optional arguments to `Pool`).

A rough example (your incomplete code makes it hard to match precisely):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import sys
import os
import time

def render_frame(i):
    #os.system(f'python main.py video_imgs/out{i}.png {convo}')
    print(f'done {i}')

def set_globals(v, c):
    global vidLoc, convo
    vidLoc = v
    convo = c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        vidLoc = sys.argv[1]
        convo = sys.argv[2]
    else:
        vidLoc = input('video: ') #! <-- this is being repeated 10 times
        convo = input('convolute cfg file: ')

    pic_list = list(range(1,num_of_pics))
    with Pool(10, initializer=set_globals, initargs=(vidLoc, convo)) as p:
        s = p.map(render_frame,pic_list)
```